# Accessing mongodb using mongoose driver

Tags: mongoose

I am using mongodb in my project and mongoose driver as interface.
Which is the better method for accessing database using monngoose driver.

```
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema(require('./models/user.js'));
var user=mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
user.findOne({'username':req.body.u_name},'email',function(err,User){});
```

or

```
conn=mongoose.connection;
conn.collection('users').findOne({'username':req.body.u_name},{'email':1},function(err,user){});
```

First method is using models and second method is using is connection.
Which method is better for accessing ?
What is difference between them ?
Thanks ..

Comment: If you're using Mongoose, you'd typically use the first one. What's prompting the question?

Comment: @JohnnyHK what about second one .

Comment: The second one bypasses Mongoose and directly uses the native driver so you lose all the Mongoose functionality.